# Java platform/lib widely use in industry

Tags: programming, quantitative, quants, library

I am currently switching from Java dev to quant and for my self-study I want to code a few auto-trading algorithms to get my hands on the subject. Are there any must know platforms/libs that I should use? Any that might be useful to know for employment as quant dev?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I suppose it will be difficult to provide a precise response as it is a fairly vague question and the reality is quite diverse.

From *my personal* experience, the Quant I used to work with are using techno as *R*, *Matlab* combined with *Visual Basic*. Regarding more sophisticated tool coded in *Java* or *C#*, they are most of the cases inhouse frameworks.

So the only advice is to play with framework that allows probabilistic computation, and read a lot about *Risk computation and Financial analysis*.

As *mgilbert* said, [Strata](http://strata.opengamma.io/) is a nice approach if you want to learn how an inhouse framework may look like. It seems quite complete and it is a good way to get familiar with the architecture of inhouse frameworks you may found in Asset Management companies.

Answer (score 1):

[Strata](https://strata.opengamma.io/)  seems like a fairly well designed library, which is an open source library designed by OpenGamma. From their docs

> Strata allows financial systems developers to build or enhance
>   existing  applications with standardized, off-the-shelf market risk
>   components.  It provides all the core concepts and market risk
>   functionality at the heart of the OpenGamma Platform, including:
>
> - Pricing, financial analytics and curve calibration
> - Reporting
> - Scenario evaluation
> - Trade modelling
> - Market data representation
> - Financial foundations - currencies, indices, holidays, date adjustments,    schedules, time-series

While I haven't actually used the library, it seems to be under active development from checking out their github page and the fact that it is backed by a large company and is being actively developed is always comforting if you are going to invest the time learning a library. I am unsure on its adoption in industry so can't comment on job prospects related to knowing the library.